# Filter and search div text by ul li click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, listjs

When you click the `li`, the `div`'s below should be filtered based on the selected `li` data values. This is working but for some reason, when you first load the page you have to click an `li` twice for the filter to work.

**[Codepin Example](http://codepen.io/omarel/pen/qaVNRG)**

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:;" class="btn dropbtn selectBedrooms">select bedrooms <span class="icon downarrow"></span></a>

    <ul id='filterFloorplans' onClick='filterFloorplans()' class="btn dropbtn">
        <li data-value="1" class="dropdown-option">1 Bedroom</li>
        <li data-value="2" class="dropdown-option">2 Bedrooms</li>
        <li data-value="all" class="dropdown-option">all</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="floorplanscontainer">
    <div class="unit">1 bedroom</div>
    <div class="unit">1 bedroom</div>
    <div class="unit">2 bedrooms</div>
</div>


<script>

    function filterFloorplans()
    {
        $('.dropdown-option').click(function () {
            var theValue = $(this).attr('data-value');

            var rex = new RegExp(theValue);

            if(rex =="/all/"){
                clearFilter()
            }else{
                $('.unit').hide();

                $('.unit').filter(function() {
                    return rex.test($(this).text());
                }).show();
            }
             $('.dropdown ul.on').removeClass("on");
        });
    }

    function clearFilter()
    {
        $('.filterFloorplans').val('');
        $('.unit').show();
    }

    $('.selectBedrooms').click(function () {
        $('.dropdown ul').toggleClass("on");
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Please format a bit your code before posting it.

Comment: use `$(document).on('event','element',function(e){});`

Comment: binding clicks inside of clicks is a BAD idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> for some reason, when you first load the page you have to click an li twice for the filter to work.

That because the first click will attach the `click` event and second will fire it.

You have to attach the event outside of the function and you don't need the function `filterFloorplans()` at all, remove the `onClick` :

```
 onClick='filterFloorplans()'
```

And define the `click` event out of the function, check the working example below.

Hope this helps.

```js
$(function(){ //ready function

  $('.dropdown-option').click(function () {
    var theValue = $(this).attr('data-value');
    var rex = new RegExp(theValue);

    if(rex =="/all/"){clearFilter()}else{
      $('.unit').hide();

      $('.unit').filter(function() {
        return rex.test($(this).text());
      }).show();
    }

    $('.dropdown ul.on').removeClass("on");
  });

  function clearFilter()
  {
    $('.filterFloorplans').val('');
    $('.unit').show();
  }

  $('.selectBedrooms').click(function () {
    $('.dropdown ul').toggleClass("on");
  });
});
```

```css
.dropdown ul li {
  width:100%;
  border:1px solid red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <a href="javascript:;" class="btn dropbtn selectBedrooms">select bedrooms <span class="icon downarrow"></span></a>
  <ul id='filterFloorplans' class="btn dropbtn">
    <li data-value="1" class="dropdown-option">1 Bedroom</li>
    <li data-value="2" class="dropdown-option">2 Bedrooms</li>
    <li data-value="all" class="dropdown-option">all</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="floorplanscontainer">
  <div class="unit">1 bedroom</div>
  <div class="unit">1 bedroom</div>
  <div class="unit">2 bedrooms</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
function filterFloorplans()
    {  
        // var rex = new RegExp($('#filterFloorplans').val());
        $('.dropdown-option').click(function () {
            var theValue = $(this).attr('data-value');

            var rex = new RegExp(theValue);

            if(rex =="/all/"){clearFilter()}else{
                    $('.unit').hide();
                    $('.unit').filter(function() {
                    return rex.test($(this).text());
                    }).show();
                }
             $('.dropdown ul.on').removeClass("on");
        });
    }
```

Write

```
$(function()
    {  
        // var rex = new RegExp($('#filterFloorplans').val());
        $('.dropdown-option').click(function () {
            var theValue = $(this).attr('data-value');

            var rex = new RegExp(theValue);

            if(rex =="/all/"){clearFilter()}else{
                    $('.unit').hide();
                    $('.unit').filter(function() {
                    return rex.test($(this).text());
                    }).show();
                }
             $('.dropdown ul.on').removeClass("on");
        });
    });
```

and remove the onClick in the ul element

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `filterFloorPlans` function.
Your JS would be like this:

```
$(function() {
   $('.dropdown-option').click(function () {
      var theValue = $(this).attr('data-value');

      var rex = new RegExp(theValue);

      if(rex =="/all/"){clearFilter()}else{
        $('.unit').hide();
        $('.unit').filter(function() {
          return rex.test($(this).text());
        }).show();
      }
      $('.dropdown ul.on').removeClass("on");
    });

    function clearFilter()
    {
      $('.filterFloorplans').val('');
      $('.unit').show();
    }

    $('.selectBedrooms').click(function () {
      $('.dropdown ul').toggleClass("on");
    });
});
```

And your HTML:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <a href="javascript:;" class="btn dropbtn selectBedrooms">select bedrooms <span class="icon downarrow"></span></a>
  <ul id='filterFloorplans' class="btn dropbtn">
    <li data-value="1" class="dropdown-option">1 Bedroom</li>
    <li data-value="2" class="dropdown-option">2 Bedrooms</li>
    <li data-value="all" class="dropdown-option">all</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="floorplanscontainer">
  <div class="unit">1 bedroom</div>
  <div class="unit">1 bedroom</div>
  <div class="unit">2 bedrooms</div>
</div>
```

You can see here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XjzKkO

Answer (score 0):

JSBIN :[**JSBIN**](http://jsbin.com/muculec/edit?html,js,output)

```
 <div class="dropdown">
          <a href="javascript:;" class="btn dropbtn selectBedrooms">select bedrooms <span class="icon downarrow"></span></a>
          <ul id='filterFloorplans' onClick='filterFloorplans()' class="btn dropbtn">
            <li data-value="1" class="dropdown-option">1 Bedroom</li>
            <li data-value="2" class="dropdown-option">2 Bedrooms</li>
            <li data-value="all" class="dropdown-option">all</li>
          </ul>

        </div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$('ul li').on('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var theValue = $(this).attr('data-value');
  var rex = new RegExp(theValue);

                if(rex =="/all/"){
                   $('.filterFloorplans').val('');
                $('.unit').show();
                                 }else{
                        $('.unit').hide();
                        $('.unit').filter(function() {
                        return rex.test($(this).text());
                        }).show();
                    }
                 $('.dropdown ul.on').removeClass("on");
})
$('.selectBedrooms').click(function () {
                $('.dropdown ul').toggleClass("on");
            });
```